# Webstorm console log size

Tags: webstorm

I have a program that generates a fair amount of output to console.log.  I'm exceeding the size of the console.log buffer and the first parts of my logs are being lost.

How can I up the size of the console so my output is not lost?

Answer (score 4):

WebStorm console buffer is currently limited to 1024 Kb. You can try increasing `idea.cycle.buffer.size` property value - see http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793.